# complex mysql query with custom sorting

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to search following result .

```
singer_id=2
---------
B9 - song's list
song_au1
song10

p7 - song's list
songx
song11

11T- song list
song 35
```

The result is actully have following requirements. 
1. show all songs by singer_id=2 order by (custom arrangement may be some or other table). 
and because i'm using PHP, I want to show result the above format..
top - singer name
then it's album type
and all songs of that album

2nd album type
and all songs of that album

..... 
I'm too much confused..

can somebody please tell me the best query!

table i've

```
 ================================================
| u_id  |  u_title |   u_song_type  | singer_id |
|================================================
|  1    | song1    |   p7           |   1       |
|  2    | songx    |   p7           |   2       |
|  3    | songpo   |   p7           |   9       |
|  4    | song_dum3|   11T          |   2       |
|  5    | song_01  |   p7           |   3       |
|  6    | song_au1 |   B9           |   2       |
|  7    | song11   |   p7           |   2       |
|  8    | song35   |   11T          |   1       |
|  9    | song10   |   B9           |   2       |
-------------------------------------------------
```

Thank

Comment: "..... I'm too much confused.." You're not alone

Answer (score 0):

After a long effort of hours. I have resolved it.

At the end I got It was easy.

```
$artistId = '2';

    echo 'Singer Id:' . $row["artistName"];

    //following query selects all records and sort records in a why i need that.
    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM  album
             ORDER BY 
             FIELD(u_song_type, 'B9','p7','11T')";         

   $result2 = mysqli_query($con,$sql2);

    //An array is defined, to filter the title only once if 
   //repeated occurrence
    $songTypesArray = array(); 

    while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
                    if (in_array($row2['u_song_type'], $songTypesArray)) {
                        //if song Type is found in the array, skip it.
                        //I left it empty. if found in array
                    }
                    else{
                        //if song type is not found in the arry we'll push
                        // song type into array 
                        array_push($songTypesArray,$row2['u_song_type']);

                        // song type only appears once if it is same
                       // in all song title.
                         echo $row2['u_song_type'];
                     }
                     //at the end song title appears.
                   echo  $row2["u_title"];
                }
           }
```

This took whole night of mind in resolution and finally it is there. I hope people would get enough help from here

Thanks